# locationd on iOS iPhone crashing every 3 secs (Location jumps)

Tags: iphone, ios

I am having a weird issue that my location on the map keeps jumping around.
Navigation and tracking my location became impossible since most apps are very confused when this happens.

Model:
iPhone 7 Plus 32 GB

What I've tried so far ...

- Turning iPhone off/on (also leave it off for several minutes)
- Turning off/on location services (also leave it off for several minutes)
- Turning off/on flight mode (also leave it off for several minutes)
- Turning off/on wifi (also leave it off for several minutes)
- Resetting location service
- Updating to latest iOS 10.3 Beta (was running 10.2.1)
- Make a full reset of my iPhone and set it up as a new iPhone
- Restoring it from backup
- Downgrade to 10.2.1 and clean iPhone install

So I guess pretty much everything one could try ...

There is a video showing the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K50Z4.jpg

Also here some of the crash reports if you are interested.

http://pastebin.com/Na3Hq3ap

http://pastebin.com/c340Eat0

Contacted apple now, will send my iPhone for repair.

This post is mainly for providing information for someone who tries to google this issue because I wasn't able to find anything helpful.

Comment: FYI Apple replaced my phone

Answer (score 1):

locationd is pretty annoying because 92% of tasks on your phone use it, along with the lack of awareness for this problem (barely any search results)
even with location services off, locationd is still being used in apps such as Camera, Photos, Reminders, Alarms, Maps, Weather, Notifications, Dialpad, Messages, and anything else that can use location services

I happened to experience locationd going over 110%, which took up all the memory, forcing apps that use locationd to freeze, resulting in having to restore a backup file, after restoring it says to 'upgrade' but does not actually upgrade, my guess is that locationd became defective after using too much memory and the restoration failed to validate it, thus replacing locationd

What I try to do is keep memory and storage AS LOW AS POSSIBLE, turn off background usage in all applications, and remember to use that app switcher every now and then.